# Appears in the NgModule.imports of ViewClientModule, but itself has errors 664 export class SharedModule { }

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular13, ng-modules

I have recently updated the angular project version from 11 to 13, after up-gradation its giving one error "**error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of VerifiedprofilesharedModule, but itself has errors
664 export class SharedModule { }**"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VchH.png)

```
my package.json

  {
  "name": "demo project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production && gzip-all && tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz './dist/out-tsc/' ",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^24.1.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^24.1.0",
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.5",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.6.3",
    "@lidorsystems/integralui-web": "^20.2.1",
    "@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom": "^1.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "@ngui/map": "^0.30.3",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^18.4.30",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^19.1.64",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-dropdowns": "^18.4.31",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^18.4.31",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-lists": "^18.4.30",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations": "^18.4.31",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-popups": "^18.4.30",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^18.4.30",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.0",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.36",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.10",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^24.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^24.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.1.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-io-overlay": "^1.2.14",
    "angular-material-datepicker": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-signature-pad": "0.0.14",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.4.0",
    "angular-ziptastic": "^1.2.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^3.0.4",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "base64-img": "^1.0.4",
    "berbix-angular": "0.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "^3.8.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-maps": "^4.3.3",
    "hellosign-embedded": "^2.10.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.2.0",
    "latinize": "^0.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.12",
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-angular": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-file-size": "0.0.4",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.9.22",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-quicklink": "^0.2.7",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.16.0",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "print-js": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2",
    "squeezebox": "^1.4.1",
    "string-mask": "^0.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "vkbeautify": "^0.99.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.3.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.166",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rebuild-node-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "net": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.7.3.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "homepage": ""
}
```

I have tried deleting node modules and re installing npm install but it didn't work, tried cache clear also that also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the **Angular migration process**, always check their migration site: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-13.0

You should also take into account that from version 13, the **ViewEngine compiler** (*which was in previous versions of Angular*) is no longer supported. Which sets up the Ivy compiler.

Also these errors can occur if the **version** of **Node.js** and **Angular** are not compatible, or the **libraries installed** in your project are no longer compatible with your current version of Angular...

> You can no longer use Angular with Node.js version 10 or older

**State of View Engine**

> View Engine is no longer available in Angular as of v13

What I advise you is to check **these steps mentioned before**.

Comment: I have used "https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-13.0" this site only for upgradation but still facing this issue